# How can I make NinjaUI work with WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, ninja

I tried to display some elements in my WordPress page and found that whenever I try to add a NinjaUI element that contains HTML, WordPress just messes it up. For instance if I say this:

```
var
$dialogCheckbox,
$dialog = $.ninja.dialog({
html: '<div style="padding: 50px">This is <b>Sparta</b>!</div>'
}).attach(function () {
```

then WordPress splits the line after the '. I can't see that being very relevant but in Safari I can see that WordPress messes with my formatting but in Firefox the page simply loads forever and I am unable to even view the source or inspect an element.

I tried various elements and was able to make the star icon show up but no other icon. (???)
I am able to show a button and I am able to show it as selected or non selected but that is basically all I have been able to do...

A button and 1 icon and nothing else :(

I tried adding the

```
<script src="/JavaScripts/jquery.ninjaui.min.js"></script>
```

to my header.php file, right below some of my other scripts and right after the jquery script but that resulted in me not being able to use the NinjaUI at all. By simply adding the jquery in the header.php and adding the ninjaui to my pages directly, that then works except not WordPress does it's formatting magic on what I place inside  tags.

for the most part I have found that if I add  tags in a WP page then I can use JavaScript just fine as long as my entire script has no empty lines. As soon as I add one empty line then the entire script section gets formatted with DIV and P tags and what not.

It seems for some reason NinjaUI corrupts some of my other plugins also.

```
<!-- All in One SEO Pack 2.0 by Michael Torbert of Semper Fi Web Design[411,447] -->
<meta name="description" content="(function ($) { var $dialog, $button = $.ninja.button({ html: 'Ninja star...'" />
```

That is coding I don't even have in my project and yet it messes up the page's description like that so I am assuming the NinjaUI wants to set the page's description to something dynamic but because it wasn't designed to work with WP it just messes up the description instead.

So all and all, I am thinking that this kit is not compatible with WordPress at all and I should make a choice between WP or this but not use both... Is that an accurate assumption or can someone help me to understand how this actually works.

I should also point out that I am a jquery noob. I have been programming for nearly 2 decades now so I understand what I'm reading but because of this I am very confused over some of my experiments. It seems that if I create my button as a variable then do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#usageButton').append($button);
$('#usageButton').append($button);
});
```

...then one button appears but the other does not. If I copy-paste the entire SCRIPT section and declare $button 3 times, then I get 3 buttons on screen. When I try to do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#usageButton').append($button);
$('#usageButtonalt').append($icon);
});
```

...it also doesn't show the second item. From my experiments it seems I can only have 1 line of code inside my .ready or else firefox just loads my page forever. Also, more confusingly, if I create my button and my icon in the same SCRIPT section but in my .ready I only append the button and make absolutely no use of the icon I declared, then the button also doesn't show up???

From my experiments it seems that I need to create a separate SCRIPT section for every single element I want to show on my page and inside each SCRIPT section I can only add 1 variable to one page element and then I need to close my SCRIPT and create a new one... I can't see why that would be required and yet that is the only way I can get anything to actually show up.

Clearly I need some assistance so any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks